# Asserting that a Set contains objects with methods that return given values

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Class A has a method, getId(), which returns a String.

Class B has a method, getCollection(), that returns a Collection (the order is undefined)

I want my test to validate that the returned collection contains instances of A, who each return expected values for getId()

```
public interface A {
    String getId ();
}

public interface B {
    Collection<A> getCollection ();
}

public class BTest {

    @Test
    public void test () {
        B b = ( ... )
        Collection<A> collection = b.getCollection();
        assertEquals(3, collection.size());

        String expId1 = "id1";
        String expId2 = "id2";
        String expId3 = "id3";

        // There should be 3 A's in this collection, each returning
        // one of the expected values in their getId()
    }

}
```

I can only think of something that would be really inelegant here. I'm currently using JUnit/Hamcrest/Mockito. If the nicest solution means library, that's not a problem

Comment: So in question format what is your question? How to assert it?

Comment: since all you are testing is the return value of the methods..it is as good as putting as iterating over your collection and put the return values in a set..and assert against expected set(of id1,id2...)

Comment: Do you mean to be testing interfaces here? What value does that provide for you?

Comment: @saud the generic is A ,if this code compiles .How can it be possible that the instances are not of A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java-8 solution, is it enough elegant?

```
public class BTest {

    @Test
    public void test () {
        B b = ( ... )
        Set<String> expectIds = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("id1","id2","id3"));
        Collection<A> collection = b.getCollection();
        Set<String> ids = collection.stream().map(a->a.getId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());

        assertEquals(3, collection.size());
        assertEquals(expectIds, ids);

    }

}
```

EDITED:

AssertJ: http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-features-highlight.html

```
public class BTest {

    @Test
    public void test () {
        B b = ( ... )
        Collection<A> collection = b.getCollection();

        assertEquals(3, collection.size());
        assertThat(collection).extracting("id").contains("id1","id2","id3");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not very elegant. Your unit test is doing additional operation not related to unit testing.

Comment: @Crazyjavahacking better?

Comment: Agreed on the first one; but your AssertJ solution looks nice, let me try it out ...

Comment: This is very cool if you're using Java8. Unfortunately not enough people are yet.

Comment: It looks like Hamcrest actually has something like this already; slightly more code than your AssertJ solution; but it avoids conflicts I'm gonna have by having Hamcrest + AssertJ's "assertThat" available to the IDE

Comment: I'll take this as an answer because it's valid, elegant, and works, thanks!

Comment: AssertJ was awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You could use Hamcrest's `containsInAnyOrder` and `hasProperty` matchers.

```
@Test
public void test () {
    B b = ( ... )
    Collection<A> collection = b.getCollection();
    assertThat(collection, containsInAnyOrder(
        Matchers.<A>hasProperty("id", equalTo("id1")),
        Matchers.<A>hasProperty("id", equalTo("id2")),
        Matchers.<A>hasProperty("id", equalTo("id3"))));
}
```

This prints a informative message in case of a failure. E.g. if the Collection has a fourth element wit id `id4`:

```
Expected: iterable over [hasProperty("id", "id1"), hasProperty("id", "id2"), hasProperty("id", "id3")] in any order
     but: Not matched: <A{id='id4'}>
```

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing after a few iterations :)

Comment: That did not work for me, I tried to assert that hasProperty and it didn't work with my class type.

Answer (score -1):

Use collection.contains (Object o) method
But you should override equals () and hashCode () for A class to have expected results for Objects

Comment: I have many other methods in there, and this one doesn't necessarily matter in terms of identifying this as unique, (using getId() was more of just an example)

Comment: If you want to check that your collection contain some instance of A you can use contains method where you pass expected A instance.

Comment: Sorry but my answer has any word about getId ().

Comment: What I'm saying is, I have more than just a getId(). Just because getId()'s are equal, it doesn't mean that the two objects are equal; therefore implementing my equals/hashcode, to be based purely on this method, doesn't make sense

Answer (score -1):

You can use Mockito to mock out interface A.

```
@Test
public void test () {
    //given: we have our expected and actual lists.
    List<String> expectedResult = Arrays.asList("id1","id2","id3");

    //build our actual list of mocked interface A objects.
    A a1 = mock(A.class);
    when(a1.getId()).thenReturn("id1");
    A a2 = mock(A.class);
    when(a2.getId()).thenReturn("id2");
    A a3 = mock(A.class);
    when(a3.getId()).thenReturn("id3");
    B b = mock(B.class);
    Collection<A> actualResult = Arrays.asList(a1, a2,a3);

    //when: we invoke the method we want to test.
    when(b.getCollection()).thenReturn(actualResult);

    //then: we should have the result we want.
    assertNotNull(actualResult);
    assertEquals(3, actualResult.size());
    for (A a : actualResult) assertTrue(expectedResult.contains(a.getId()));

}
```